# Missing sdb1 on new flash drive, but works ok

Tags: mount, partition, flash-memory

recently in the lab we bought some HDs and a new flash drive for research stuff. My surprise was when I tried to connect them to linux. Gnome mounted them normaly, but did not exist the /dev/sdb1 partition, the system only seen /dev/sdb. In that momment was an "emergency service", then I created a new partition table on the HDs/stick and everything worked fine, but now I want understand what happened there. Mainly because some scripts broke since they were looking for /dev/sdb1 specifically.

I tried to search about, but I don't know how to start. Some advice?

Comment: Too much info is missing - was the drive gpt partitioned, while your partition tool only knows "msdos" style partitions? Or maybe the drive was never partitioned in the first place? When you say "mounted" - what do you mean? Usually mount only refers to a filesystem

Comment: Thank you for answer. 1) The system can use gpt, I was trying to reproduce the conditions formating other drive as gpt but the partitions are showed normally. 2) When I said mounted, it was realy mounted. Nautilus popped up the empty directory (I have write privilegies). I think that the drive was never partitioned. I thought that mount non-partitioned system was impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing magic. You can create filesystem on a bunch of sequential blocks. It can be a block device, a partition, a file or a ramdisk... An iso file also doesn't contain any partition, but we can mount easily as loopback device.
For example you can create more partitions on floppy disks (/dev/fd0) but it is very pointless on 1.44mb.

Comment: I think that that is the key! Thank you! It was very close to mount a CD/DVD, you mount the device, but you don't have partitions. Now I am trying to figure out how to create that kind of drives.

Comment: Ok, now I know how to create that system. I useed gparted to create a _loop_ partition table. Then formated the device as fat32. I think that this configuration was the factory settings. Thank you for help me to understand.